# Any widget on flutter to show microphone equalizer visual showing?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am developing flutter app which shows the audio equalizer visual like linefrom, waweform. Anyone knows the plugin or widget or layout to show this type of visual on screen.

Comment: if you are looking for visuals for waves, and lines i will recommend https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter this package.

Comment: @kishanvekariya i am looking widget which take audio from device and show equalize visuals on screen.

Comment: did you find anything related to this ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking for a solution: I found this package
https://pub.dev/packages/audio_visualizer

all its features are described in the package repository.